# Why is the reflection of CFL bulb a green spot on my glasses

Tags: optics, reflection, lenses

Why is that if i try to see the reflection of a CFL bulb (the bulb is on) using my glasses i see it as 2 green spots instead of a white light.
plus this happens on the outerside of the lenses...not the part through which I would see outside..i hope its clear in the image

[image][image]

And eventually after sometime the screen turns pink

[image]

I cant assume my lenses are reflecting green light cause if so i shouldn't be able to see anything green wearing it right?....can someone explain the reason behind this.

Comment: And i dont know much information about my lenses....like if its UV protected, the power, etc.... cause i bought this when i was a kid.

Comment: It could have to do with anti-reflective coating (or lack thereof) like in [these images](https://www.google.ca/search?client=ubuntu&hs=5Wr&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=VosqXbWyOrS_0PEP4IO44A8&q=coated+eyeglasses+anti-reflective&oq=coated+eyeglasses+anti-reflective).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that for me.....i had this messing my head for weeks now